# Plain TeX `\footline` with rule and content

Tags: header-footer, plain-tex

It seems pretty trivial to replace the footer with either content or a line in Plain TeX:

```
\footline={\centerline{\folio}}   % page number in footer
\footline={\hrulefill}            % rule in footer
```

Doing both, I don't see what the trick is. I seem to need vertical mode but the tricks I expect to work do not: creating a `\vbox` around it, using `\par`.

I see in the TeXBook this piece of code:

```
\def\makefootline{\baselineskip=24pt \line{\the\footline}}
```

I also tried replacing my `\footline=` attempts with `\def\makefootline` but wasn't able to get it to work.

I tried all of these and got various errors:

```
\footline={\par\hrulefill\par\centerline{\folio}}
\footline={\vbox to 0.5in{\... (as above)}}
\def\makefootline{... both variants above}
```

One error was `! Leaders not followed by proper glue.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of `\footline` is used as argument to `\line`, which is `\hbox to \hsize`: restricted horizontal mode is in force, so `\par` has no effect.

You want to use `\vtop` or `\vbox`; here's the example with the former:

```
\input plipsum

\footline={\vtop{\hrule\smallskip\centerline{\folio}}}

\lipsum{1-20}

\bye
```

[image]

If you instead prefer to have 24pt from the last baseline on the page to the baseline of the page number, use `\vbox`:

```
\input plipsum

\footline={\vbox{\hrule\smallskip\centerline{\folio}}}

\lipsum{1-20}

\bye
```

[image]

Adjust the separation between rule and page number to suit yourself.